# How can I convert .mat files to NumPy files in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a .mat file
It is a little over 1 GB but I don't know how much data or lines of code is on it. I want to convert this .mat file to a NumPy file in Python so I can look at the data and see what is in it. How do I do this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options to read it.

1. Reading it in python:

   import scipy.io
   mat = scipy.io.loadmat('fileName.mat')
2. Converting it to `.csv` in MATLAB in order to read it in python later:

   FileData = load('FileName.mat');
   csvwrite('FileName.csv', FileData.M);